# Bad resolution after boot with unconnected HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I use Debian Bullseye with `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` (for various reasons).

I want my Raspberry Pi to boot with HDMI enabled with 1080p resolution even if HDMI is unconnected during boot.
Everything works well if HDMI is connected during boot.
However, if HDMI is not connected during boot, I get 1024x768 video resolution.

My config.txt is configured as follow :

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=1920
framebuffer_height=1080

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_force_mode=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

max_framebuffers=2

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]

dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=10000000,interrupt=26,spimaxfrequency=1000000
dtoverlay=spi0-hw-cs
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
dtoverlay=disable-bt
gpu_mem=128
```

I thought that

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_force_mode=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_drive=2
```

would be enough, but it's not the case.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing `hdmi_group` , `hdmi_mode` and `hdmi_drive` to values that support 1080P?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080` was needed.

This ignores the EDID data and helps to force a resolution.
More details in the documentation : https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html

Now, it boot with 1080p resolution even with no HDMI connected during boot.

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I edited my answer to add precisions